# MySQL Joining two rows, two tables, with the same fields

Tags: php, mysql, join, alias

Hi Im new to MySQL and PHP, and this is my first post..  So please bear with me.
I am trying to add two tables and two rows from one table
`friends`

```
member_ID | friend_ID | status
```

and a `user` table

```
member_ID | username
```

What I am trying to do is combine both tables for a friend request, `friends.member_ID` is the `user.member_ID` sending the request, `friends.member_ID`, is the `user.member_ID` that is being requested, `status` is when they accept the request it will turn `0` to `1` which will make the relationship true.

so far, I have this for my query to display all these fields to show who has requested this person as a friend

```
SELECT users.member_ID, friends.member_ID, friends.friend_ID, friends.status 
FROM `users` , `friends` 
WHERE friends.status=0   
AND users.member_ID = friends.member_ID
AND friends.member_ID = users.member_ID
AND users.member_ID = 6 (this will be $_SESSION[member_ID] when I add it to php)
```

I understand you can use an alias but I am a bit confused

Please help, my assignment is due tomorrow, and there is still so much to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this with join

```
 SELECT users.member_ID, friends.member_ID, friends.friend_ID, friends.status 
 FROM `users` 
 INNER JOIN `friends` 

 ON users.member_ID = friends.member_ID
 WHERE friends.status=0 
 AND users.member_ID = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Column alias - use AS(/as) after column name

```
users.member_ID as uId, friends.member_ID as fId
```

Table alias - define after table name

```
users u , friends f
```

If using table aliases, you can use them when selecting your column names

```
u.member_ID as uId, f.member_ID as fId
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/problems-with-alias.html

```
SELECT u.member_ID as uId, f.member_ID as fId, f.friend_ID as ffId, f.status as fStatus
FROM `users` u 
INNER JOIN `friends` f

ON u.member_ID = f.member_ID
WHERE f.status=0 
AND u.member_ID = 6
```

Aliases are useful when you are selecting 2 or more columns with the same name from multiple tables - `users.member_ID, friends.member_ID`. Instead of using an ambiguous `$row['member_ID']` or having to use `$row[0]/$row[1]`, you can use `$row['uID']/$row['fID']`

Comment: thanks this helps, the query comes with 0, but I think I have to play around with it.

Comment: Could it be that you want `ON u.member_ID = f.friend_ID` as you are wanting `to show who has requested this person as a friend`? With `u.member_ID = f.member_ID`  I think you are selecting where `u.member_ID` is the friend requester, not the friend requested